# Javascript error while executing alert function through php

Tags: php, javascript

I am using fusion maps in one of my application.

In one of the example i have to pass the value from one map to another charts,

I am facing one problem if the data passed is numeric its displaying alert message correctly but if it is a string it generates an error:

```
NM is not defined
```

javascript:alert(NM)()

My code is as below:

```
$strXML .= "<entity id='" . $rs1['Internal_Id'] . "' value='" . round((($rs1['datap'] /  $sumdata) * 100),2) . "' link='javascript:alert(".($rs1['Internal_Id']) . ")'  />";
```

If i change the link part (passing single quotes in alert)that is:

```
$strXML .= "<entity id='" . $rs1['Internal_Id'] . "' value='" . round((($rs1['datap'] /  $sumdata) * 100),2) . "' link='javascript:alert('".($rs1['Internal_Id']) . "')'  />";
```

It displays invalid xml data.

Please help me on this

Thanks

Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

Use `\"` rather than `'` to surround the JavaScript string.

```
$strXML .= "<entity id='" . $rs1['Internal_Id'] . "' value='" . round((($rs1['datap'] /  $sumdata) * 100),2) . "' link='javascript:alert(\"".($rs1['Internal_Id']) . "\")'  />";
```

What is happening is that the xml produced is like so:

```
<entity id='NM' value='1' link='javascript:alert('NM')'/>
```

Which as you should be able to see from SOs syntax highlighting ends the value for the link attribute after `javascript:alert('` as you are using the same quotes for the javascript as you are using for surrounding the attribute values.

Using a different quote (`"` rather than `'`) doesn't end the attribute value (again see the syntax highlighting)

```
<entity id='NM' value='1' link='javascript:alert("NM")'/>
```

In PHP we have to escape the quote (Using `\`) so it isn't interpreted as a special character by the php interpreter and used to end the string, which is why in php you have to write `\"`

Answer (score 0):

You should change your

```
ink='javascript:alert('".($rs1['Internal_Id']) . "')'
```

by

```
ink='javascript:alert(\"".($rs1['Internal_Id']) . "\")'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply but now it shows this error missing ) after argument list

Comment: Seems you $rs1['Internal_Id'] has some non word character like " or , or )

Comment: If u don't mind, can you let us know what is your $rs1['Internal_Id'] value

Comment: Hi,

It has a string value like 'AK', 'UK'

Even if i am giving static text value its generating an error.

Comment: Pankaj have you seen by reversing the ' with " like 'javascript:alert(\"".($rs1['Internal_Id']) . "\")'
by link="javascript:alert('".($rs1['Internal_Id']) . "');\"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$strXML .= "<entity id='" . $rs1['Internal_Id'] . "' value='" . round((($rs1['datap'] /  $sumdata) * 100),2) . "' link='javascript:alert(\"".($rs1['Internal_Id']) . "\")'  />";
```

Basically escaping your alert quotation marks :)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply but now it shows this error missing ) after argument list